# FormArray clears values (but not controls) after pushing a new FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm trying to push a FormGroup (myGroup) into a FormArray (myArray), that already has a bunch of FormGroups inside. After pushing myGroup I log myArray.value, which then only consists of myGroups value. BUT: the myArray.controls still contains all of the other formGroups.

Anyone experienced this behavior or has any idea, why this happens? Already searched the web, but could not find anything related.

```
// at this point the array contains n values and n controls
console.log(this.myArray.value)  

// then I push the new group (result comes from input data of the user)
const myGroup = this.myService.createGroup(result);
(<FormArray>this.myArray).push(<FormGroup>myGroup);

// at this point the array contains only one value, but still n controls
console.log(this.myArray.value);
```

myService:

```
createGroup(result: Result) {
  return this.fb.group({
    id: this.fb.control(result.id),
    name: this.fb.control(result.name)
  });
}
```

There are a few things, that might be relevant here:

1. If I update one of the existing FormGroups inside myArray with patchValue, it behaves like normal, everything works fine.
2. Initially I fill myArray dynamically using the same method as I use later on at pushing myGroup (createGroup()), which also works as expected.
3. The form is nested. My current structure is: myForm -> contains myParentArray -> contains myParentGroup -> contains myArray.
4. I create the whole form initially in the parent component using a service, that returns eg. FormGroups like myGroup. Then I pass the FormGroups and FormArrays via @Input() to the nested components. But that should not make a difference in my opinion.

What I already tried is updating the value with .updateValueAndValidity(), but that does not work.

Maybe there is any way to enforce FormArrays to update their value based on the controls?

Comment: hard to tell from here but I don't think FormGroups should be anywhere in a service since it's a UI concern. Having said that, are you dealing with multiple instances of your service? If your service is provided in multiple modules, that might be a source of your error?

Comment: can you please show where `this.myArray` comes from ?

Comment: @Mohamed Ali RACHID `get myArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.myParentForm.get('myArray');
  }`

Comment: and myParentForm is passed into the component via `@Input() myParentForm: FormGroup;`

Comment: @vidalsasoon it's injected into the root, so should be the same instance, no?

Comment: @lajuma ya it should be OK

Comment: can you please explain `at this point the array contains only one value, but still n controls` ? what do you mean by one value ?

Comment: `console.log(this.myArray.value);` results in `[ 0: { ... } ]`, but `console.log(this.myArray);` results in `0: FormGroup(), 1: FormGroup(), ...` trying to say that the controls still contain all of the FormGroups, but the value is only the pushed FormGroups value.

Comment: the second one should be `console.log(this.myArray.controls)`...

Comment: I don't know if is this, but remember that if a control is disabled this.myArray.value dont take care about it. you must use this.myArray.getRawValue() in this case

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, never thought of that, because I never disable the formArray anywhere. but your solution works just fine and you're right, somehow the status becomes disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in my case was simply getting the values by .getRawValue() as @Eliseo pointed out. But the main mistake was, that at some other part of the code, formControls inside the formArray were disabled, which caused the original problem.